# How to create a Line Chart with a scaled X Axis and Dummy Variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm intending on creating a line chart with three Lines. The Final X axis will display the Values shown in column `Time Period`. But I am using the column `Days` as a dummy variable to get the axis spaced correctly.

[image]

Here is what I have so far but you can see clearly that the x-axis is not spaced properly and that I am waiting to swap the dummy variable names for the correct names until after the X Axis is spaced to scale.

[image]

Please be so kind as to provide a step by step description on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a category axis. So, just point the the axis labels to the correct column. In my screenshot, the axis category labels are from the text in column A, not from the numbers in column B.

[image]

If you want to space the axis according to the values, you need to use column B for the axis and configure the axis to be a Date Axis.

[image]

Then

- add another series with all 0 values, which will be a line on the X axis
- add data labels "below" to that series and configure the labels to use **Values from Cells**. Point to the text in column A.
- format the axis to have no labels
- format the helper series to have no line.
- delete the helper series from the legend.

With this axis setting some of the data points on the left are very close together and further and further apart to the right, you will always have overlapping labels and there is not much you can do about that.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for this answer!